Move LUKSHeader from /dev/sdx1 to /dev/sdx
I've got a machine running ubuntu 23.10 with some LUKS-Encrypted disks attached. Unfortunately I think I made some mistakes when creating the Filesystems, as some of the luksHeaders are in /dev/sdX and some are in /dev/sdX1. I'm trying to write a script at the moment which asks me for the password once and then mounts all the drives. This however is more difficult if the headers aren'n uniformly in /dev/sdX. Is there a way I can move the headers from /dev/sdX1 to /dev/sdX without data loss?
Any help would be appreciated,
kind regards

I do not use LVM, but most that do, suggest having gpt partitions. Or change all to sdXY, not sdX. The also suggest not having one LVM across multiple drives as loss of one drive, loses all data. And with encryption you must have good backup  & restore procedure. As if any issue cannot be fixed within about an hour, better to just reinstall & restore from backup. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2461714 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2459660&p=14027975#post14027975

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is with writing your script, but you can decrypt/mount partitions by their UUID instead of device name. Use lsblk -f to get the UUID for each partition (careful, use the one of the encrypted partition, not the one of the mapped, decrypted device).
